# Hibernate query for left outer join with null id condition

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hql, jpql, hibernate-criteria

Is any hibernate query similar to the following query?

MySql Query >> **select * from mother mot left join children ch on ch.mid = mot.id  where ch.id is null**

mot.id - *primary key of mother*

ch.mid - *foreign key*

ch.id - *primary key of children*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select m from mother m left join m.childrens ch 
 where ch.mid = m.id and ch.id is null
```